# R: Consolidating duplicate observations?

Tags: r, consolidation

I have a large data frame with approximately 500,000 observations (identified by "ID") and 150+ variables.  Some observations only appear once; others appear multiple times (upwards of 10 or so).  I would like to "collapse" these multiple observations so that there is only one row per unique ID, and that all information in columns 2:150 are concatenated.  I do not need any calculations run on these observations, just a quick munging.

I've tried:

```
df.new <- group_by(df,"ID")
```

and also:

```
library(data.table)
dt = data.table(df)
dt.new <- dt[, lapply(.SD, na.omit), by = "ID"]
```

and unfortunately neither have worked.  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Are the observations that appear more than once the same for every column? If so, `unique(dt)` would work.

Comment: No, for variables/columns 2:150, there are different values that I need to retain.  When there is more than one ID, the rows themselves are not duplicates, just the ID#.

Comment: Just do `dt[, lapply(.SD, toString), by = ID]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using basic R:

```
df = data.frame(ID = c("a","a","b","b","b","c","d","d"),
                day = c("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8"),
                year = c(2016,2017,2017,2016,2017,2016,2017,2016),
                stringsAsFactors = F)

> df
  ID day year
1  a   1 2016
2  a   2 2017
3  b   3 2017
4  b   4 2016
5  b   5 2017
6  c   6 2016
7  d   7 2017
8  d   8 2016
```

**Do:**

```
z = aggregate(df[,2:3], 
              by = list(id = df$ID), 
              function(x){ paste0(x, collapse = "/") }
              )
```

**Result:**

```
> z
  id   day           year
1  a   1/2      2016/2017
2  b 3/4/5 2017/2016/2017
3  c     6           2016
4  d   7/8      2017/2016
```

**EDIT**

If you want to avoid "collapsing" NA do:

```
z = aggregate(df[,2:3], 
              by = list(id = df$ID), 


        function(x){ paste0(x[!is.na(x)],collapse = "/") })
```

For a data frame like:

```
> df
  ID  day year
1  a    1 2016
2  a    2   NA
3  b    3 2017
4  b    4 2016
5  b <NA> 2017
6  c    6 2016
7  d    7 2017
8  d    8 2016
```

The result is:

```
> z
  id day           year
1  a 1/2           2016
2  b 3/4 2017/2016/2017
3  c   6           2016
4  d 7/8      2017/2016
```

Comment: This looks to have done the trick!  Thank you!  One additional question: to omit any NAs, would it read: "na.action=na.omit", "na.action=na.pass", or "na.rm=TRUE"?  I placed each of these after the last " } " in the statement, but none worked, saying they were unused arguments.

Comment: @Oryx added the change to avoid NA

Answer (score 0):

What about?

```
df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise_each(funs(paste0(., collapse = "/")))
```

Or [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)...

```
iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarise_each(funs(paste0(., collapse = "/")))
```

Comment: That could possibly work.  However, I'm not just dealing with one dependent variable ("Sepal.Length"): I have over 150.  Is there a way to reference all of those without having to do each name individually?  Perhaps a column index?

Comment: Like using `summarise_each`? See above - I've changed the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar problem in the past, but I wasn't dealing with several copies of the same data. It was in many cases just 2 instances and in some cases 3 instances. Below was my approach. Hopefully, it will help.

```
idx <- duplicated(df$key) | duplicated(df$key, fromLast=TRUE) # get the index of the duplicate entries. Or will help get the original value too.
dupes <- df[idx,] # get duplicated values
non_dupes <- df[!idx,]  # get all non duplicated values

temp <- dupes %>% group_by(key) %>%  # roll up the duplicated ones.
  fill_(colnames(dupes), .direction = "down") %>%  
  fill_(colnames(dupes), .direction = "up")  %>%  
  slice(1)
```

Then it is easy to merge back the `temp` and the `non_dupes`.

**EDIT**

I would highly recommend to filter the `df` to the only the population as much as possible and relevant for your end goal as this process could take some time.